# how to send an email by setting the templateid using php tool kit --->Single email method

Tags: integration, php

1) I am trying to  send an email using PHP  Tool kit when the records (Candidate) is created.

I have read the documentation from here [Send Single Email Message](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_11.0_SendEmail_Sample_(Enterprise))

2) I tried setting the settemplateId instead of plainTextbody.

but not able to send the emails.Can anyone resolve this for me.

**Code**

```
 $singleEmail1 = new SingleEmailMessage();
$singleEmail1->toAddresses = $_POST['email'];
$singleEmail1->plainTextBody = "Please save this email for your reference";
$singleEmail1->subject = "Thank You Submitting your resume";
$singleEmail1->saveAsActivity = true;
$singleEmail1->emailPriority = EMAIL_PRIORITY_LOW;
echo "***** Send Emails *****\n";
$emailResponse = $mySforceConnection->sendSingleEmail(array ($singleEmail1));
print_r($emailResponse);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while sending email using setTemplateId you need to consider following points

1. When you use templateId you need targetObjectId as well.
2. As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setTargetObjectId) Targetobjectid can be only record id of (Lead,Contact,User) and it is always required if you are using templateId

After considering above point your code will look like this.

```
        $singleEmail1 = new SingleEmailMessage();
        $singleEmail1->settargetObjectId('LEAD_CONTACT_USER_RECORD_ID');
        $singleEmail1->setTemplateId('TEMPLATE_RECORD_ID');
        $singleEmail1->saveAsActivity = false;
        $singleEmail1->emailPriority = EMAIL_PRIORITY_LOW;
        echo "***** Send Emails *****\n";
        $emailResponse = $mySforceConnection->sendSingleEmail(array ($singleEmail1));
        print_r($emailResponse);
```

As you can see from above code I have removed **toAddress** methods becasue email will go to that recordID (Contact,Lead,User) all those object has emailId field itself.

Comment: Thank you very much.I have another question can you please look in to it for me [](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/103323/form-passing-null-values-to-php-post-method-for-dates-fields-php-tool-kit-sales)

Comment: can you please look at the Question   [link](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/103323/php-tool-kit-is-not-allowing-to-pass-null-values-from-the-html-form-for-date-fi) .This is very important for me to complete the requirement .